# Click of BackButton to a specific page of a QWizardPage

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have a set of pages, the pages proceed linearly forward, however I would like to, when the user clicked on the backbutton of last page (page 9), the page returns two previous pages (page 7). But I want this application only on backbutton of the last page, others buttons and backbuttons must return linearly.

How can I do this?